# Methods for describing higher level categories (aggregate summarized values or all original values)?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, survey

Let's say there is this questionnaire-based study:

A restaurant serves these 2 categories: Food ("f") and Drink ("d"). Each respectively has hamburger (f1), fries (f2), and fried chicken (f3); coffee (d1), tea (d2), and juice (d3).

15 testing customers tasted these 6 items. After finishing an item, each tester enters his response on a 7-point Likert scale question on how delicious the item was. So, pooling these 15 testers' responses together, we can get the mean, std-dev, etc. of each of the 6 items.

But how do we calculate the overall "delicious level" of the 2 higher level categories (Food, Drink)? Methods in consideration: (A) For Food category, its mean/std-dev/etc. will be the average of f1, f2, and f3's mean/std-dev/etc. Same goes for Drink category; (B) For Food category, its mean/std-dev/etc. should be pooling all the 45 values (15 (testers) x 3 (f1, f2, f3)) together for calculation. Same goes for Drink category.

Which of (A) and (B) should we use to calculate the mean/std-dev/etc. of 2 higher level categories (food, drink)?